# I feel acidity after running

Tags: running, cardio, treadmill

Daily i run for 15 minutues on treadmill. After 10 minutes, it started feeling of acidity in food pipe. What would you like to suggest in this context?

Comment: Are you eating within a couple hours before exercising?

Comment: Yes i take snacks and tea 3 hours before exercise. but i think its quite long time.

Comment: That is a long time. I would lean towards Gastro-Esophageal-Reflux-Disease or something similar, but that would definitely be something to see a doctor about.

Comment: Hmm thanks Rohin Ashe, I would see doc very soon. Moreover, I drink lot of water in a day to combat it.

Comment: Actually, that might contribute. Cut back on how much water you drink (so you only drink a bit when you're thirsty, rather than drinking what you think you need to) and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, see a doctor.  We can't diagnose you on the internet.  I would lean toward acid reflux or something similar.  There are so many things it possibly **could** be that I wouldn't take the chance.  I found a link on a forum where a group of runners discussed this problem extensively which may be of use to you http://www.runnersworld.com/community/forums/runner-communities/marathoners/acid-reflux-running.

Comment: I agree, I would see a doctor to make sure that nothing else is going wrong. I got the camera shoved down my throat to make sure nothing else is wrong. You might not be feeling it when you are not running and it can lead to bigger issues. I was a silent refluxer, rarely felt it, but my throat showed the signs of a problem. Daily OTC meds and no more issues.